# Return a Json object after successful POST to API endpoit

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I am trying to authenticate a user and then return a json object of relevant Session information.
The user only hits the endpoint with their username and password, which i then validate. If successfull, a new object should be returned. However it wont allow me to change the type being returned.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public async Task<ActionResult<User>> Authenticate([FromBody] User user)
{
   var response = await _authenticateService.Authenticate(user);
   return response;
 }
```

**Interface**

```
public interface IAuthenticationService
    {
        Task<User> Authenticate(User user);
    }
```

**Service**

```
    public async Task<User> Authenticate(User user)
    {
        //Authenticate User
        ......
        //Authentication Successful
        SuccessObject authenticationSuccessObject = new SuccessObject()
        {
            Success = "true",
            SessionId = new Guid().ToString()
        };

        return authenticationSuccessObject;
    }
```

The response being returned should be a JSON object but i get an error "Can not implicitly convert Type"

What is it that i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why not return Ok(response)?

Comment: Maybe because you return your object into the async Task<User> method?

Comment: @Shanie -- is correct. You can use `return Ok(response);`, or if it failed, you could use `return NotAuthorized(response);`. There are a plethora if responses to choose from.